# How to turn a column into a row via JMESPath in Google sheets?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, jmespath

Good afternoon!
I am working on api integration with google sheets using the API to Sheets extension https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/api_to_sheets/245778206812.
Can't solve JMESPath Query problem, need your help

Initial code

```
{
    "result": {
        "postings": [
            {
                "posting_number": "49382959-0024-1",
                "order_id": 633398070,
                "order_number": "49382959-0024",
                "status": "delivered",
                "delivery_method": {
                    "id": 22038534499000,
                    "name": "Ozon Логистика самостоятельно, Москва",
                    "warehouse_id": 22038534499000,
                    "warehouse": "Московская обл., г. Видное, ул. Завидная 19",
                    "tpl_provider_id": 24,
                    "tpl_provider": "Ozon Логистика"
                },
                "tracking_number": "",
                "tpl_integration_type": "ozon",
                "in_process_at": "2022-04-08T04:56:02Z",
                "shipment_date": "2022-04-09T10:00:00Z",
                "delivering_date": "2022-04-09T07:14:26Z",
                "cancellation": {
                    "cancel_reason_id": 0,
                    "cancel_reason": "",
                    "cancellation_type": "",
                    "cancelled_after_ship": false,
                    "affect_cancellation_rating": false,
                    "cancellation_initiator": ""
                },
                "customer": null,
                "products": [
                    {
                        "price": "7970.0000",
                        "offer_id": "R22301Е",
                        "name": "Смеситель для ванны и душа Pursh R22301Е черный, нержавеющая сталь",
                        "sku": 300454648,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "mandatory_mark": [],
                        "currency_code": ""
                    }
                ],
                "addressee": null,
                "barcodes": null,
                "analytics_data": {
                    "region": "Ульяновская Область",
                    "city": "Ульяновск",
                    "delivery_type": "PVZ",
                    "is_premium": false,
                    "payment_type_group_name": "Карты оплаты",
                    "warehouse_id": 22038534499000,
                    "warehouse": "Московская обл., г. Видное, ул. Завидная 19",
                    "tpl_provider_id": 24,
                    "tpl_provider": "Ozon Логистика",
                    "delivery_date_begin": "2022-04-16T13:00:00Z",
                    "delivery_date_end": "2022-04-16T17:00:00Z",
                    "is_legal": false
                },
                "financial_data": {
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "commission_amount": 637.6,
                            "commission_percent": 8,
                            "payout": 7332.4,
                            "product_id": 300454648,
                            "old_price": 15900,
                            "price": 7970,
                            "total_discount_value": 7930,
                            "total_discount_percent": 49.87,
                            "actions": [
                                "Системная виртуальная скидка селлера",
                                "Маркетплейс промо №4"
                            ],
                            "picking": null,
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "client_price": "",
                            "item_services": {
                                "marketplace_service_item_fulfillment": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_pickup": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_pvz": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_sc": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_ff": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_direct_flow_trans": -54,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_flow_trans": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_not_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_part_goods_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_after_deliv_to_customer": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "posting_services": {
                        "marketplace_service_item_fulfillment": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_pickup": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_pvz": -45,
                        "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_sc": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_ff": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_direct_flow_trans": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_flow_trans": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_deliv_to_customer": -350,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_not_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_part_goods_customer": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_after_deliv_to_customer": 0
                    }
                },
                "is_express": false,
                "requirements": {
                    "products_requiring_gtd": [],
                    "products_requiring_country": [],
                    "products_requiring_mandatory_mark": []
                }
            },
            {
                "posting_number": "07227925-0084-1",
                "order_id": 633125045,
                "order_number": "07227925-0084",
                "status": "delivered",
                "delivery_method": {
                    "id": 22038534499000,
                    "name": "Ozon Логистика самостоятельно, Москва",
                    "warehouse_id": 22038534499000,
                    "warehouse": "Московская обл., г. Видное, ул. Завидная 19",
                    "tpl_provider_id": 24,
                    "tpl_provider": "Ozon Логистика"
                },
                "tracking_number": "",
                "tpl_integration_type": "ozon",
                "in_process_at": "2022-04-07T21:20:13Z",
                "shipment_date": "2022-04-09T10:00:00Z",
                "delivering_date": "2022-04-09T07:14:34Z",
                "cancellation": {
                    "cancel_reason_id": 0,
                    "cancel_reason": "",
                    "cancellation_type": "",
                    "cancelled_after_ship": false,
                    "affect_cancellation_rating": false,
                    "cancellation_initiator": ""
                },
                "customer": null,
                "products": [
                    {
                        "price": "2763.0000",
                        "offer_id": "LА1061W",
                        "name": "Белый однорычажный смеситель для раковины (умывальника) из нержавеющей стали, Lemen",
                        "sku": 519731707,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "mandatory_mark": [],
                        "currency_code": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "price": "2677.0000",
                        "offer_id": "R933O3W",
                        "name": "Высокий однорычажный смеситель для кухни, Pursh, белый, нержавеющая сталь",
                        "sku": 545484671,
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "mandatory_mark": [],
                        "currency_code": ""
                    }
                ],
                "addressee": null,
                "barcodes": null,
                "analytics_data": {
                    "region": "Московская Область",
                    "city": "Красногорск",
                    "delivery_type": "Courier",
                    "is_premium": false,
                    "payment_type_group_name": "Карты оплаты",
                    "warehouse_id": 22038534499000,
                    "warehouse": "Московская обл., г. Видное, ул. Завидная 19",
                    "tpl_provider_id": 24,
                    "tpl_provider": "Ozon Логистика",
                    "delivery_date_begin": "2022-04-11T09:00:00Z",
                    "delivery_date_end": "2022-04-11T19:00:00Z",
                    "is_legal": false
                },
                "financial_data": {
                    "products": [
                        {
                            "commission_amount": 221.04,
                            "commission_percent": 8,
                            "payout": 2541.96,
                            "product_id": 519731707,
                            "old_price": 9900,
                            "price": 2763,
                            "total_discount_value": 7137,
                            "total_discount_percent": 72.09,
                            "actions": [
                                "Системная виртуальная скидка селлера",
                                "Маркетплейс промо №4"
                            ],
                            "picking": null,
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "client_price": "",
                            "item_services": {
                                "marketplace_service_item_fulfillment": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_pickup": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_pvz": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_sc": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_ff": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_direct_flow_trans": -37.8,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_flow_trans": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_not_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_part_goods_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_after_deliv_to_customer": 0
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "commission_amount": 214.16,
                            "commission_percent": 8,
                            "payout": 2462.84,
                            "product_id": 545484671,
                            "old_price": 6750,
                            "price": 2677,
                            "total_discount_value": 4073,
                            "total_discount_percent": 60.34,
                            "actions": [
                                "Системная виртуальная скидка селлера",
                                "Маркетплейс промо №4"
                            ],
                            "picking": null,
                            "quantity": 1,
                            "client_price": "",
                            "item_services": {
                                "marketplace_service_item_fulfillment": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_pickup": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_pvz": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_sc": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_ff": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_direct_flow_trans": -43.2,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_flow_trans": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_not_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_part_goods_customer": 0,
                                "marketplace_service_item_return_after_deliv_to_customer": 0
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "posting_services": {
                        "marketplace_service_item_fulfillment": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_pickup": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_pvz": -45,
                        "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_sc": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_dropoff_ff": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_direct_flow_trans": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_flow_trans": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_deliv_to_customer": -272,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_not_deliv_to_customer": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_part_goods_customer": 0,
                        "marketplace_service_item_return_after_deliv_to_customer": 0
                    }
                },
                "is_express": false,
                "requirements": {
                    "products_requiring_gtd": [],
                    "products_requiring_country": [],
                    "products_requiring_mandatory_mark": []
                }
            }
        ],
        "has_next": false
    }
}
```

JMESPath

```
result.postings[].{posting_number:posting_number, products:products[].offer_id}
```

[Gives me data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoyII.png)

[But I need the data to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bz9K1.png)

[And it was like in the last picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gpmv.png)

In other words how to turn a column into a row via JMESPath

Please help!

Comment: The generic _turn a column into a line_ is not something feasible, now if you want to achieve it on a limited set of `product.n`, this is possible with some hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function colintorow(col=1) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const column = [sh.getRange(1,col,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat()];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(column));
}
```